# Splitting addresses in Excel with no delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hopefully a quick one, I have a spreadsheet with 63,000 addresses on it that I need to separate into several different columns. `ADDRESS 1, ADDRESS 2, TOWN, COUNTY`.

There isn’t any consistency with the data ... it’s come out of an old piece of software where no data standards we followed.

Example formats (all in one column)

```
ADDRESS 1 - ADDRESS 2 - TOWN
ADDRESS 2 - TOWN
TOWN
ADDRESS 1 - COUNTY
```

What would be the best way to solve this? I need to update the values as it’s being imported into a new system.

Cheers,

Comment: There is no quick, easy, canned way of doing this. Address splitting, even well formed addresses, is a tough thing to solve. Even if you farmed each address out to Google maps API and took whatever it returned you would have a high number of bad matches.

Comment: As long as human intelligence is required to figure out what the address actually consists of, automation of this process is impossible. As the saying goes "Garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: If you actually want a result, I suggest you send it off to a third party that specialises in data cleansing/data matching.

Comment: 63000 is not a huge number. Since you are migrating from old system to the new one, this is just a one time thing.  The time you spent to search for a professional solution could be more than just do it in manually and fix some exceptions. E.g. 1) Group the records by no. of " - ",  2) split the rows by " - ". I believe this pretty much fix a big portion. If you have a list of potential town / county, then this would be much faster.